# JSF Validation Set Property

Tags: validation, jsf

How can I get JSF to set the property regardless of whether validation fails? I want the question.response object below to be set if validation fails.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="questionId" value="#{question.response}" 
                validator="#{question.validate}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="You must answer the question to continue"
                class="radio-btn-set">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Yes" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="No" />
    <p:ajax update="msgQuestion" oncomplete="clearEmptyRows()" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: This is a reverse thing. Isn't it a flaw in the requirement as no operation should proceed / propagate towards the upper layers once a conversion / validation fails?

Comment: I understand that you're already forcing a validation error when an answer is invalid? Perhaps you shouldn't do that and check it in the action/listener method instead.

Comment: Invalid values per definition have no sense in the Model. You could have a third value in your menu, lets say "Sometimes". Then you could establish that "Sometimes" will be invalid depending on the question number (for Yes/No answers). In these cases you will not want this value in your Model, you will only want to show a message to the user. So, an invalid value is not the same as an incorrect value.

Comment: @BalusC My issue is if I have a yes/no form where the question bean is session scoped. When I refresh the page, only the valid answers remain. I want to set the property but stop the user from proceeding when they submit the form and display the error message.